# How to use Q objects to test list membership?

Tags: python, django, django-q

With normal Django querysets, if I want to retrieve all the myObjects whose "a" attribute is 1, 2 or 3, I would do the following:

```
myObjects.objects.filter(a_in=[1,2,3])
```

But I would like to do this using the Q objects. How would I write the equivalent query with Q objects?

Comment: Have to ask, if its working with `_in`, why do you want it done with `Q`?

Comment: As I see it, it should be working right away. What's wrong?

Comment: Good question. In my code, I was using regular query-sets for all my database accesses. However, some queries became too complicated and required "or" operations so I had to switch them to Q objects. 

For the sake of maintainability and uniformity, I would like to use the same technique for all my DB accesses. So now I'm replacing all my querysets with Q objects. Isn't that a good enough reason?

Comment: Umm, no that's not a good reason and its not adding any maintainability. Its a case of fixing something that isn't broken. Its actually making your code _less_ maintainable because of the conventions of `Q` objects (which are - as you discovered - useful for _or_ queries as most of the default API is "and" queries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
myObjects.objects.filter(Q(a = 1) | Q( a = 2) | Q( a = 3))
```

I don't know why you want to do that but you can also do

```
myObjects.objects.filter(Q(a__in=[1,2,3])
```

Answer (score 2):

It works right away.

```
Q(a__in=[1, 2, 3])
```

Probably your issue is that you were using a single underscore instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

```
q = Q(a__in=[1,2,3])
#q = Q(('a__in', [1,2,3]))
myObjects.objects.filter(q)
```

**Edit**: Bah never mind, tuple not needed.